# Error pops after running my first kivy code to display a blank screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm using pycharm and of course I'm new to kivy. I did the installation and everything as prescribed by a blog. And also kivy is there in my IDE packages list. Still I get following errors

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Container(GridLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Awesome app!!!'
        return Container()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

### Result

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 /root/PycharmProjects/suraj/first_class.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-09-23_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (default, Jun 27 2018, 14:40:03) 
[GCC 8.1.0]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/root/PycharmProjects/suraj/first_class.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 26, in <module>
     from kivy.clock import Clock
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 362, in <module>
     from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy._clock'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please provide the installation commands used to install Kivy.

Comment: @ikolim its --------   pip install kivy, after i updated my sources.list as per kivy installation guide for debian.

Comment: Try installing Kivy as per [Installation on Linux (Debian / Ubuntu / Kubuntu / Xubuntu / Lubuntu (Saucy and above))](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html)